# How to find "invoke_user_function" function for Python 3.8 runtime for Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, python-3.7, python-3.8

I'm currently working on a personal project which requires me to access runtime parameters of Google Cloud Functions. Google Cloud Functions
supports 2 runtimes currently, Python 3.7 & Python 3.8.

I wrote the following code for Python 3.7 runtime:-

```
from google.cloud import functions as func

def hello_world(request):
    print(dir(func))
    print(dir(func.worker_v1))
    print(dir(func.worker_v1.FunctionHandler))
```

I got the following output:-

```
[
'_USE_WORKER_V2', '_USE_WORKER_V2_VAR', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__',
'os', 'worker_v1', 'worker_v2'
]

[
'FunctionHandler', 'HTTPException', 'LogBuffer', 'LogInfo', 'LoggingWorker', 'NoLoggingWSGIRequestHandler', 'TEMPLATE_FOLDER', 'WSGIRequestHandler', 'WSGIServer',
'_CODE_LOCATION', '_CONTAINER_LOGGING_ENABLED', '_CRASH', '_ENTRY_POINT', '_EXECUTE_PREFIX', '_Event', '_FUNCTION_NAME', '_FUNCTION_STATUS_HEADER_FIELD',
'_FUNCTION_TRIGGER_TYPE', '_FUNCTION_VERSION', '_GOOGLE_CLOUD_DEBUG_ENABLED', '_GOOGLE_CLOUD_TRACE_ENABLED', '_GOOGLE_CONTAINER_LOGGING_ENABLED', '_HTTP_TRIGGER',
'_IPv6Server', '_LOAD_ERROR', '_MAX_LOG_BATCH_ENTRIES', '_MAX_LOG_BATCH_LENGTH', '_MAX_LOG_LENGTH', '_SUPERVISOR_HOSTNAME', '_SUPERVISOR_INTERNAL_PORT',
'_SUPERVISOR_LOG_PERIOD_SEC', '_SUPERVISOR_LOG_TIMEOUT_SEC', '_TRACER', '_TRACE_ENABLED', '_URL_PATTERN', '_WORKER_PORT',
'__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_adjust_response_with_trace_header', '_adjust_trace_span',
'_adjust_user_request', '_datetime_now_utc', '_ensure_leading_slash', '_function_handler', '_remove_prefix', '_url_with_slash_after_hostname',
'app', 'asyncio', 'check_or_load_user_function', 'check_worker', 'collections', 'datetime', 'event_context', 'flask', 'io', 'json', 'logging', 'main', 'make_server',
'os', 'post_to_supervisor', 'queue', 're', 'redirect_stdout_and_stderr', 'requests', 'routing', 'run_background_function', 'setup_logging', 'signal', 'socket', 'sys',
'threading', 'time', 'traceback', 'try_enable_tracing', 'util'
]

[
'__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__',
'__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__',
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_user_function',
'flush', 'has_user_function', 'invoke_user_function', 'load_user_function', 'log_user_error'
]
```

As you can see above, there is a "invoke_user_function" function, which is the exact function which I need.

Now, I'm getting these results for Python3.7 runtime environment, but for Python 3.8 I'm not getting these results.

For Python 3.8 runtime, I wrote the following code:-

```
from google.cloud import functions as func

def hello_world(request):
    print(dir(func))
    print(dir(func.context))
    return "string"
```

I got the following output:-

```
['Context', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

I'm nowhere getting the "invoke_user_function" function which I need for my project in case of Python3.8 runtime.

Important question : Has anyone faced this situation before and know where to find this in case of Python3.8 ?

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated this on my side, so I can confirm that it's not working. However [Python 3.8 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime) is in Beta phase, so it's not ready yet.

If you need this you can try to go to support page part [Beta tester group](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/getting-support#beta_tester_group)
This should be better place to do raise this question.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I need to go to the Beta tester group for this issue.